# Converting timestamp to a different timezone in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've combed through Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp-functions) multiple times, but I can't seem to find a simple function (within a `SELECT` query) to convert a UTC timestamp to a different timezone, which in my case is Pacific. For most international timezones, I can simply use `TIMESTAMP_SUB` or `TIMESTAMP_ADD` to subtract/add offset hours, but the United States use of daylight savings time complicates things (unnecessarily!).

Did I miss something in the documentation? Or is there some other way to easily convert to another timezone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TIMESTAMP` type is tied to UTC. When you convert a `TIMESTAMP` to some other type that isn't tied to a particular timezone, such as `STRING`, `DATE`, or `DATETIME`, you can specify the timezone for the conversion, e.g.:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
               AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') AS current_pst_day;
```

If you want the (current) number of hours between different timezones, you can use `CURRENT_DATETIME()` with different timezones and take the difference:

```
SELECT
  time_zone,
  DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(time_zone),
                CURRENT_DATETIME(), HOUR) AS hours_from_utc
FROM UNNEST(['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York']) AS time_zone;
+---------------------+----------------+
| time_zone           | hours_from_utc |
+---------------------+----------------+
| America/Los_Angeles | -8             |
| America/New_York    | -5             |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

To make the offsetting more convenient, you can wrap this into a SQL function, then call it to add the offset to a particular timestamp:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION OffsetForTimeZone(t TIMESTAMP, time_zone STRING) AS (
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(t, INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(time_zone),
                                          CURRENT_DATETIME(), HOUR) HOUR)
);

SELECT OffsetForTimeZone(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Keep in mind that the result of this is still a `TIMESTAMP` tied to UTC, albeit offset by the current difference between that and Pacific time.

Comment: I'm a SQL/BigQuery newb so I didn't know I could even write my own function inside a query! I guess this will have to do unless Google adds this as a built-in function.

Comment: Just to add, there is also `format_timestamp` which returns a String and can handle timezones - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Elliott's answer, I wanted to test if the timezone math worked around daylight savings changes:

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-07-01') x, 'summer' season
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01') x, 'winter' season
)

SELECT
  season,
  time_zone,
  DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(x, time_zone),
                DATETIME(x), HOUR) AS hours_from_utc
FROM UNNEST(['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York']) AS time_zone
CROSS JOIN dates 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

It does:

```
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| season |      time_zone      | hours_from_utc |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| summer | America/Los_Angeles |             -7 |
| summer | America/New_York    |             -4 |
| winter | America/Los_Angeles |             -8 |
| winter | America/New_York    |             -5 |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

It's even aware that Chile didn't go through DST in 2015:

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2014-07-01') x
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-07-01') x
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-07-01') x
)

SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x),
  time_zone,
  DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(x, time_zone),
                DATETIME(x), HOUR) AS hours_from_utc
FROM UNNEST(['Chile/Continental', 'America/New_York']) AS time_zone
CROSS JOIN dates 
ORDER BY 2,2


+------+-------------------+----------------+
| f0_  |     time_zone     | hours_from_utc |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2014 | America/New_York  |             -4 |
| 2015 | America/New_York  |             -4 |
| 2016 | America/New_York  |             -4 |
| 2014 | Chile/Continental |             -4 |
| 2015 | Chile/Continental |             -3 |
| 2016 | Chile/Continental |             -4 |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: :o) try 'America/Phoenix' and 'America/Los_Angeles' - I was expecting to see one hour difference - but got `-7` for both

Comment: Google says -7 too  :) http://i.imgur.com/VH8hkyX.png (LA has -8 above.. how did you get -7?)

Comment: but it is 7:04 right now in Phoenix whereas it is just 6:04 in LA. That is what I wanted to point out

Comment: got it. let me check why i suddenly got -7 for both. i just used you code in answer above btw. still thank you for quick check and reply :o)

Comment: oh, I see  - i used your second code and it has summer only time, so that is why both returned -7, when i changed it to winter time - i got what I expected

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - _"It's even aware that Chile didn't go through DST in 2015"_. That's most impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Since originally posting my question, I've simply been using the `TIMESTAMP_SUB` function with an offset to convert the default UTC timestamp to my desired timezone; I didn't use Elliot's elegant solution above because it required me to create a function, which Tableau's custom SQL feature doesn't allow.

For anyone interested, I've now found an alternate solution, albeit ugly as it is. BigQuery does allow built-in timezone offsets (e.g., "America/Los_Angeles") when converting from one format to another. For example, going from timestamp to datetime:

`SELECT DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),"America/Los_Angeles")`

The example goes from the current UTC time to Pacific time. However, it's now in a datetime format, which Tableau doesn't recognize as a date/time object. To get it back into timestamp format, I enclosed the function above into a `TIMESTAMP` function:

`SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),"America/Los_Angeles"))`

Silly, inelegant, and around 20% slower, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE("America/Los_Angeles")
```