# Convert list of times from different timezones into UTC with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of stores that are all in different timezones.  I want to take these stores and convert them all to be using UTC instead of their local timezone.  I can see how I can do the opposite but how would I be able to do this via bigQuery?

My thought was to use something like this and timestamp_sub to do this manually.

```
SELECT
  time_zone,
  DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(time_zone),
                CURRENT_DATETIME(), HOUR) AS hours_from_utc
FROM UNNEST(['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York']) AS time_zone;
```

[Opposite example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574300/converting-timestamp-to-a-different-timezone-in-bigquery)

example data:

| Location | time_zone | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US/Eastern | 2016-02-12T23:04:00Z |
| 2 | US/Alaska | 2016-02-12T23:04:00Z |
| 3 | America/Puerto_Rico | 2016-02-12T16:47:00Z |
| 4 | US/Pacific | 2016-02-12T20:11:00Z |
| 5 | US/Central | 2016-02-12T20:14:00Z |
| 6 | US/Arizona | 2016-02-12T12:22:00Z |
| 7 | US/Mountain | 2016-02-12T21:06:00Z |
| 8 | US/Hawaii | 2016-02-12T19:25:00Z |

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Also can you confirm the underlying data type is either datetime or timestamp?

Comment: Thank you @DanielZagales I added some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

With the function [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp), you can convert the date to UTC.

> This function supports an optional parameter to specify a time zone.
> If no time zone is specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used.

You can see this example with some example data from different time zones.

```
with Dates as (
 
   SELECT "Store 1" as store,"2022-01-02 00:00:00" as time, "America/Los_Angeles" as time_zone
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "Store 2" as store,"2022-01-03 00:00:00" as time, "Europe/Berlin" as time_zone
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "Store 3" as store,"2022-01-03 00:00:00"as time, "America/New_York" as time_zone
)
 
select
    store
   ,time_zone
   ,time
   , TIMESTAMP(time, time_zone  ) AS UTC
   , DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(time_zone),CURRENT_DATETIME(), HOUR) AS hours_from_utc
   from Dates
```

You can see the output data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update but one quick question, are the UTC times in this example (and it looks the same on my instance) an hour off?  I checked them against this website:  https://www.freeconvert.com/time/pst-to-utc